# Problems in using ?: as if statement in C++

Tags: c++

I am now writing a program that calculates the arctangent of two numbers and I would like to use ?: as a if statement to simplify my code. 
As the atan of zero over zero is minus infinity, I added a statement such that if the absolute value of the calculated atan is greater than 90, the result should be equal to 90 degrees. 
However, the output of my code is -2147483648 instead of 90. What is thee problem of my code? Thank you very much!
.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> abc(1);
    int a=0,b=0;
    abc[0]=abs((int)(atan((float)a / b) * 180 / M_PI)) > 90 ? 90 : (int)(atan((float)a / b) * 180 / M_PI);
    cout<<abc[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add more parenthesis in your expression. BTW, it is too long and unreadable, so split your instruction in several pieces.

Comment: Your value is exactly the minimum value of a 32-bit integer. You almost certainly have an issue with your C-style cast to an integer: a logic error in your own code.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then **use the debugger**

Comment: @Alexander Huszagh
Would you mind explaining the logic error in my code?

Comment: You're dividing by zero.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch 
Where should I add the parathesis?
I have tried (abs((int)(atan((float)a / b) * 180 / M_PI))) but I did not work.

Comment: Try much more. Feel free to try several things. Don't expect us to do your homework. You could introduce extra variables, e.g. `float x= (float)a / b;` etc...

Comment: Your repeating `abs((int)(atan((float)a / b) * 180 / M_PI))` is reprehensible. Although I don't subscribe to the "unreadable" argument (my counter to that is that you should learn to read code, however complex), repeating formulas like this is sloppy and prone to error. And what's with all the casting? Trust the C++ standard.

Comment: That said, I don't understand the downvoting. The question is well-written with supporting code.

Comment: @Bathsheba 
How could I simplify my code if I do not declare a new variable storing abs((int)(atan((float)a / b) * 180 / M_PI))?
It is because in my program, there would be three vector like abc which calculates actangent and it may be messy to use the new variable for the three statements.

Comment: @knownothingaboutprogramming: That's *exactly* what you should do. A new variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be honest, just use [`atan2`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan2/). It saves you all the trouble to code the logic.

Also, `atan2(0,0)` will give you domain error as specified. Imagine drawing a line from origin to origin and ask what is the angle between the line and positive x-axis, it can literally be any angle, thus undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The value of a and b is zero. Inizialize this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code print -2147483648.
Try the following code. It should print 90, as expected. (I rewrote some of the headers you included in your code.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> abc(1);
    int a=0,b=0;
    abc[0]=abs((int)(atan((float)a / b) * 180 / M_PI)) > 90 ? 90 : (int)(atan((float)a / b) * 180 / M_PI);
    cout<<abc[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Remember to compile using

```
g++ main.cpp
```

Comment: I think that code is quite similar to my original code except the header included are different. Could you explain why it will work when using cmath library?